# center text in undersized div

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to get text centered inside a fixed with div, which will allow overflow, but I can't seem to get it to center inside the div.

I've made a jsfiddle to show you what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/mdHKZ/3/

The problem is that once the text begins to overflow the div, it will no longer be centered. However, I can't expand the div, because that would defeat the purpose of me having a fixed width div. Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible to do this dynamically with straight css, but if you know the width of your text ahead of time you could specify a negative margin-left on the contents: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdHKZ/6/)

If you wanted to do this dynamically (i.e. to have the text centered in a small div for any width of text) I think you'd have to use javascript.

*Edit*: Here's an updated jsFiddle with the margin set using jQuery: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdHKZ/10/)

HTML:

```
<div class="contents">
    <span id="hack">Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text</span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var $hack = $('#hack');
var innerWidth = $hack.width();
var outerWidth = $hack.parent().width();
if(innerWidth > outerWidth) {
    var marginLeft = -1 * (innerWidth - outerWidth)/2;
    $hack.css('margin-left', marginLeft);
}
```

CSS:

```
.contents {
  margin-left: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I think I might have to do that then. How would I determine the size of the text though?

Comment: I think the code in my update is a reasonable way of determining non-wrapping text width - i.e. wrap it in an inline element and get the width of that element.

Answer (score 0):

change overflow to "auto" instead of "visible"

Comment: that will just create a scroll bar

Comment: oh i see, you want it to center on top of the div tag when it doesn't fit - 1 sec, lemme play with your fiddle

Comment: see my other answer, need more space:

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what the width of the div inside is going to be?  I'm not sure if you'll be able to get to do it automatically based on a variable width.  I was able to get to center with a static width:

```
<div style="margin-left: 150px; text-align: center; width: 100px; overflow: visible; white-space: nowrap; border: 1px solid; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div style="width:200px;margin-left:-100px;">Sample Text Sample Text SamText Sampl eple </div>
</div>
```

I had to set the width to 200px and then substract half of it with margin-left.  I couldn't get it to work with something more generic like "margin-left: 50%", because it will only shift left -75px (half of 150px) from the outter div